# Unique index or primary key violation when persist a new element

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am creating an application and when saving a new item I get the following error:

```
2019-03-17 00:05:09 WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-03-17 00:05:09 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_3 ON PUBLIC.LOJA_DOCUMENTO(ID_DOCUMENTO) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
/* insert br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento */ insert into loja_documento (codigo_documento, descricao_documento, id_pessoa, valor_documento, id_documento) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-198]
2019-03-17 00:05:09 ERROR o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2019-03-17 00:05:09 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_3 ON PUBLIC.LOJA_DOCUMENTO(ID_DOCUMENTO) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
/* insert br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento */ insert into loja_documento (codigo_documento, descricao_documento, id_pessoa, valor_documento, id_documento) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-198]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_3 ON PUBLIC.LOJA_DOCUMENTO(ID_DOCUMENTO) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
/* insert br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento */ insert into loja_documento (codigo_documento, descricao_documento, id_pessoa, valor_documento, id_documento) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-198]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:103) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.checkUnique(MVSecondaryIndex.java:220) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.add(MVSecondaryIndex.java:196) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:703) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:180) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:132) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:133) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:267) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:200) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:154) ~[h2-1.4.198.jar:1.4.198]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3171) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3686) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:533) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.odin.loja.backend.service.DocumentoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$25558288.save(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.odin.loja.backend.controller.DocumentoController.save(DocumentoController.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

My Model Class Documento.Java

```
package br.com.odin.loja.backend.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(name = "loja_documento")
public class Documento {

    // Attributes
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, precision = 3, scale = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO", allocationSize=1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CODIGO_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "VALOR_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String valor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PESSOA")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "documentos", allowSetters = true)
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    // Constructors

    // Getters & Setters
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    // Methods

}
```

My Repository DocumentoRepository.Java

```
package br.com.odin.loja.backend.repository;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Pessoa;

@Repository
public class DocumentoRepository {

    // Attributes
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // Methods
    public Documento save(Documento documento) {
        entityManager.persist(documento);
        return documento;
    }

    public List<Documento> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Documento").getResultList();
    }

    public Documento findById(Integer id) {
        return entityManager.find(Documento.class, id);
    }

    public List<Documento> findByTipo(String tipoSearch) {

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Documento> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Documento.class);
        Root<Documento> documento = criteriaQuery.from(Documento.class);
        TypedQuery<Documento> typedQuery;

        criteriaQuery.where(
                criteriaBuilder.like(
                        documento.<String>get("codigo"), "%" + tipoSearch + "%"));

        typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }

    public Boolean removeById(Integer id) {
        Documento documento = this.findById(id);

        try {
            entityManager.remove(documento);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Documento update(Documento documento) {
        return entityManager.merge(documento);
    }
}
```

My Service DocumentoService.Java

```
package br.com.odin.loja.backend.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.com.odin.loja.backend.exception.DocumentoInvalidoException;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Pessoa;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.repository.DocumentoRepository;

@Service                // Expoe a classe como um serviço do spring 
@Transactional          // Marca a classe com gerenciamento de transações (SPRING)
public class DocumentoService {

    // Attributes
    @Autowired
    private DocumentoRepository documentoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PessoaService pessoaService;

    // General Methods
    private void validateRg(String rg) throws DocumentoInvalidoException {

        if (rg.length() < 9) {
            throw new DocumentoInvalidoException("Número de caracteres inválidos! Favor verificar.");
        }

        if (rg.contains("-") || rg.contains(".")) {
            throw new DocumentoInvalidoException("Digite o CPF sem pontuação ou traço! Favor verificar.");
        }

        if (rg.length() > 9) {
            throw new DocumentoInvalidoException("Número de caracteres inválidos! Favor verificar.");
        }
    }

    private void validateCpf(String cpf) throws DocumentoInvalidoException {

        if (cpf.length() < 11) {
            throw new DocumentoInvalidoException("Número de caracteres inválidos! Favor verificar.");
        }

        if (cpf.contains("-") || cpf.contains(".")) {
            throw new DocumentoInvalidoException("Digite o CPF sem pontuação ou traço! Favor verificar.");
        }

        if (cpf.length() > 11) {
            throw new DocumentoInvalidoException("Número de caracteres inválidos! Favor verificar.");
        }
    }


    public String getFilterProperty(String filter) {
        if (filter != null) {
            return filter.substring(0, filter.indexOf("="));    
        }
        return "default";
    }

    public String getFilterValue(String filter) {
        return filter.substring(filter.indexOf("=") + 1, filter.length());
    }

    // API Methods
    public List<Documento> find(String filter){

        switch (getFilterProperty(filter)) {

            case "tipo":
                return findByTipo(getFilterValue(filter));

            case "id":
                Documento documentoResult = findById(Integer.parseInt(getFilterValue(filter)));
                List<Documento> listDocumento = new ArrayList<Documento>();
                listDocumento.add(documentoResult);
                return listDocumento;

            default:
                return findAll();       
        }
    }

    public Documento findById(Integer id) {
        return documentoRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Documento> findByTipo(String tipoSearch) {
        return documentoRepository.findByTipo(tipoSearch);
    }

    public List<Documento> findAll() {
        return documentoRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Documento save(Documento documento) throws DocumentoInvalidoException{
        try {

            if (documento.getCodigo().equals("RG")) {
                validateRg(documento.getValor());   
            } 

            if (documento.getCodigo().equals("CPF")) {
                validateCpf(documento.getValor());
            }

            Pessoa pessoa = pessoaService.findById(documento.getPessoa().getId());
            pessoa.setDocumentos(null);
            documento.getPessoa().setId(pessoa.getId());
            return documentoRepository.save(documento);
        } catch (DocumentoInvalidoException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error message: " + exception.getMessage());
            throw new DocumentoInvalidoException(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Boolean removeById(Integer id) {
        return documentoRepository.removeById(id);
    }

    public Documento update(Documento documentoAlterado, Integer id) {
        documentoAlterado.setId(id);
        return documentoRepository.update(documentoAlterado);
    }

}
```

My Controller DocumentoController.Java

```
package br.com.odin.loja.backend.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.odin.loja.backend.exception.DocumentoInvalidoException;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Documento;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.model.Pessoa;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.service.DocumentoService;
import br.com.odin.loja.backend.service.PessoaService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/documentos")
public class DocumentoController {

    //Attributes
    @Autowired
    private DocumentoService documentoService;

    // API Methods
    @GetMapping("")
    public List<Documento> find(@RequestParam(value="filter", required = false) String filter) {
        List<Documento> documentoList = documentoService.find(filter);

        for(int i = 0; i < documentoList.size(); i++) {
            documentoList.get(i).getPessoa().setDocumentos(null);   
        }
        return documentoList;
    }

    @PostMapping("/novo")
    public Documento save(@RequestBody Documento documento) throws DocumentoInvalidoException {
        return documentoService.save(documento);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Documento findById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return documentoService.findById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}/remover")
    public Boolean remove(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return documentoService.removeById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}/alterar")
    public Documento update (@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody Documento documento) {
        return documentoService.update(documento, id);
    }

}
```

I'm using h2 database and have some data save in database

db.sql

```
-- Pessoas

INSERT INTO LOJA_PESSOA (id_pessoa, nome_pessoa) VALUES (1, 'Teste 1');
INSERT INTO LOJA_PESSOA (id_pessoa, nome_pessoa) VALUES (2, 'Teste 2');
INSERT INTO LOJA_PESSOA (id_pessoa, nome_pessoa) VALUES (3, 'Teste 3');

-- Documentos

INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (1, 'CPF', 'CPF', '99988877766', 1);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (2, 'RG', 'RG', '998887776', 1);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (3, 'CPF', 'CPF', '11122233344', 2);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (4, 'RG', 'RG', '112223334', 2);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (5, 'CPF', 'CPF', '98765432199', 3);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (6, 'RG', 'RG', '987654321', 3);
```

**Update**

As I read the comments and analyzed my data.sql I solved the problem by changing the sql date so that it uses the sequence generated by the database. 
The new data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO.nextval, 'CPF', 'CPF', '99988877766', 1);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO.nextval, 'RG', 'RG', '998887776', 1);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO.nextval, 'CPF', 'CPF', '11122233344', 2);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO.nextval, 'RG', 'RG', '112223334', 2);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO.nextval, 'CPF', 'CPF', '98765432199', 3);
INSERT INTO LOJA_DOCUMENTO (id_documento, codigo_documento, descricao_documento, valor_documento, id_pessoa) VALUES (SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO.nextval, 'RG', 'RG', '987654321', 3);
```

Comment: I think it's due to your sequence `SEQ_LOJA_DOCUMENTO` is in its initial state. It generates ID = 1 on persist, which is getting collide with rows you inserted by hands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer a.yekimov. Yes, from what I could understand, that's it. But how do I do to hibernate automatically get the number of items added to the table, generate the next id and save in that new id?

Comment: I suggest to modify your sql script to increment the sequence, after you inserted rows. I don't know the way to tell to hibernate that its IDs generator is out of sync. It may be reasonable big value, say 10k or 100k to not calculate inserted rows.

Comment: You're using Spring already; any specific reason you're not using Spring Data? Also, (1) use constructor injection instead of field injection and (2) `novo`, `remover`, and `alterar` are redundant (that's the purpose of using `@DeleteMapping`; treat the URI as the ID of the resource and use the plain one for operations on an existing object and just `/` for your POST).

Comment: Chrylis, thanks for your comment, I'm learnig spring framework (Concepts and Methods), after that, I will use Spring Data. In this first step I want to use just Spring. Could you please describe your item 1 better? How to do it? Or a link for consultation?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have encountered exactly same error. I had answered the same problem in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69367655/12097072).

**TLDR:**

To resolve this issue pass primary key column value as unique and not NULL. just simply add `NOT NULL UNIQUE` at the end of your DDL.