# Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.xxx"; SQL statement

Tags: java, spring, h2

I keep getting the following error message whenever my application boots up:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.SERMON_SESSION(ID)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (id, session_enum) VALUES ('1', 'SUN_MRN'), ('2', 'SUN_EVE'), ('3', 'TUE_BIB'), ('4', 'FRI_BIB'), ('5', 'WKD_CNF') [23505-197]
```

How can I fix this? I have to assign the sermon session id myself as it is used in later columns.

**application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:erc;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=classpath://resources/data.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
logging.level.com.erc.api.*=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=OFF
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=INFO
logging.level.org.jaudiotagger=WARN
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=60MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=60MB
application.sermon_path=classpath://resources/files/sermons/}
```

**SermonSession.java**

```
@Table(name = "sermon_session", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id", "sessionEnum"}))
@Entity
public class SermonSession {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private SessionEnum sessionEnum;

    public SermonSession(String session) {
        setSessionEnum(session);
    }

    public SermonSession() {
        this.sessionEnum = null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{ id: %d, session_enum: %s }", getId(), getSessionEnum());
    }

    String getSessionEnum() {
        return this.sessionEnum.getSession();
    }

    private void setSessionEnum(String session) {
        this.sessionEnum = SessionEnum.fromSession(session);
    }

    private int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (id, session_enum)
VALUES ('1', 'SUN_MRN'),
       ('2', 'SUN_EVE'),
       ('3', 'TUE_BIB'),
       ('4', 'FRI_BIB'),
       ('5', 'WKD_CNF');
```

Changing data.sql to:

```
INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (session_enum)
VALUES ('SUN_MRN'),
       ('SUN_EVE'),
       ('TUE_BIB'),
       ('FRI_BIB'),
       ('WKD_CNF');
```

Produces the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_AA7KWY8HO9GLHF1VI4HDB61X8_INDEX_8 ON PUBLIC.SERMON_SESSION(SESSION_ENUM) VALUES ('SUN_MRN', 1)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (session_enum) VALUES ('SUN_MRN'), ('SUN_EVE'), ('TUE_BIB'), ('FRI_BIB'), ('WKD_CNF') [23505-197]
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (id, session_enum) VALUES ('1', 'SUN_MRN')` will insert the id, too. At least it tries to do so... Have a look at the column definition of `id`. It may be configured as `UNIQUE` and/or `AUTO INCREMENT`, which means the database will handle the id and you have to insert the values for the remaining columns only (`INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (session_enum) VALUES ('SUN_MRN')`);

Comment: Hi @deHaar, many thanks for your reply. Please see update

Comment: Hmm... This `('SUN_MRN', 1)` is somehow suspicious because the order of the values is obviously reversed compared to your first try. Can you provide the definition of the table or the column `id`?

Comment: Hi the definition of the table is above: `SermonSession.java` can be seen in the question and the enum is here: https://pastebin.com/E6eMuW7u.

Comment: @methuselah any progress there? I'm trying to do the same thing and getting the same `JdbcSQlException`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` will allow an automatic unique ID generation, no need to put it there yourself.

The following should be more than enough

```
DELETE FROM SERMON_SESSION;
INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (session_enum)
VALUES ('SUN_MRN'),
       ('SUN_EVE'),
       ('TUE_BIB'),
       ('FRI_BIB'),
       ('WKD_CNF');
```

Comment: I've tried this and now get the error message: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_AA7KWY8HO9GLHF1VI4HDB61X8_INDEX_8 ON PUBLIC.SERMON_SESSION(SESSION_ENUM) VALUES ('SUN_MRN', 1)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO SERMON_SESSION (session_enum) VALUES ('SUN_MRN'), ('SUN_EVE'), ('TUE_BIB'), ('FRI_BIB'), ('WKD_CNF') [23505-197]`

Comment: @methuselah What does you `enum` look like? It smells fishy to me that the enum column should be unique too..

Comment: @methuselah try to truncate the table before inserting the values. I just edited my answer

Comment: I have tried this and get the error: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Cannot truncate "PUBLIC.SERMON_SESSION"; SQL statement:
TRUNCATE TABLE SERMON_SESSION [90106-197]`

Comment: @methuselah You probably have constraints on it. Try the following `DELETE FROM SERMON_SESSION`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue recently. The problem might be, that when you are not closing your application gracefully(you are not posting a message to the endpoint for application to shutdown), session manager might not have the opportunity to perform drop (see this topic: [Spring boot ddl auto generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113154/spring-boot-ddl-auto-generator)).

The solution we have found out is to manually drop the database and change

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Why exactly is that? I'm still waiting for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060870/difference-between-spring-jpa-hibernate-hbm2ddl-and-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl) here.

Comment: I have tried this and get the error: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Cannot truncate "PUBLIC.SERMON_SESSION"; SQL statement: TRUNCATE TABLE SERMON_SESSION [90106-197]`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I solved it by changing my query like this in flyway:

```
INSERT INTO crawl_template (id, template, domain) VALUES (NEXTVAL('CRAWL_TEMPLATE_ID_SEQ'), 'woo', 'example.com');
```

so in summary it is solved by adding `NEXTVAL`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got the exactly same error message. It didn't affect my CRUD operation but still annoying to see. I followed [this article](https://facingissuesonit.com/2019/07/16/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception-unique-index-or-primary-key-violation/) to resolve this error.

**TLDR**

To resolve this issue pass primary key column value as unique and not NULL. just simply add `NOT NULL UNIQUE` at the end of your DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can solved this issue by adding this annotation to the id propertie
@GeneratedValue